# Xamarin Android App crash : System.ArgumentException'jobject' must not be IntPtr.Zero. Random app crash

Tags: android, xamarin

Hi we are currently developing a cross platform app using Xamarin forms with a PCL project.

Or app works like a gem on iOS. However on android, we seem to be hitting this unpredictable random crash. Upon observing xamarin insights this is the stack trace that i got:

```
System.ArgumentException'jobject' must not be IntPtr.Zero. Parameter name: jobject
Raw
Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod(IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jmethod)
Android.Animation.Animator.Cancel()
Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AndroidTicker.DisableTimer()
Xamarin.Forms.Ticker.Disable()
Xamarin.Forms.Ticker.SendSignals(int timestep)
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AndroidTicker.<.ctor>b__0 (System.Object sender, Android.Animation.AnimatorUpdateEventArgs e) <0xd6bdc460 + 0x0001f> in <filename unknown>:0
Android.Animation.ValueAnimator.IAnimatorUpdateListenerImplementor.OnAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation)
Android.Animation.ValueAnimator.IAnimatorUpdateListenerInvoker.n_OnAnimationUpdate_Landroid_animation_ValueAnimator_(IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_animation)
at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:58d57b72-260d-44c0-954f-016b48334d23 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
```

I did find similar posts on stack overflow. Looking for anyone who has encountered and fixed this issue.

Also we are hesitant to update our Xamarin forms as that seems to introduce more bugs than resolving issues.

Comment: It's a peer connection issue; the `AndroidTicker` has had `Dispose()` called and its Java counterpart has been GC'd. Do you implement `IAnimatorUpdateListenerImplementor` yourself or is it hidden beneath the Xamarin.Forms assembly layer? If it's in Xamarin.Forms then you need to file a bug with Xamarin.

Comment: @matthewrdev the IAnimatorUpdateListenerImplementor is hidden beneath Xamarin.Forms assembly I don't implement it. We are still in Xam forms 1.4.3. I think the latest Xam Forms is 2.0.4. I plan on doing updating to latest Xam forms and trying once more. Will relay this info to my senior dev. Will get back to you on progress. Thanks

Comment: I'd definitely fling a bug report at the Xamarin team. I see these issues frequently in Xamarin.Forms as well. Painful to see when you know what it is, how to fix it but don't have access to the source :/ I hope everything goes well for you. Do you want me to put this information into an answer so other people know what to look for?

Comment: @matthewrdev I would love for you to expound on your comments as an answer to this (what to look for, maybe an example of the 'bad' code that leads to this, etc....) I've gotten this in my own code (non-Form based) and it took quite awhile to nail down where I was losing a reference.

Comment: My 2 cents: I repeatedly had issues with Xamarin Forms when I didn't do a "clean solution" after making an edit to a XAML file. Can you try a cleanup, build the solution again and see if things work better?

Comment: @SushiHangover I'll expand on my comment but in this case its a Xamarin.Forms bug :(

Comment: @matthewrdev yes please put this information into an answer. That will help others. I am currently planning to have our QA guys test with the latest Xam forms and see if the issue is fixed. If not then I plan to file a bug with Xamarin. Will keep you posted how that goes. Thanks again.

Comment: Found this Xamarin bug:https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=24286 looks related